# UIButton.configuration in Swift and Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

I noticed, that `configuration` property of `UIButton` is implemented(?) differently in Swift and Objective-C.
In UIButton header `configuration` is of `UIButtonConfiguration` type which is a class.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy, nullable) UIButtonConfiguration *configuration API_AVAILABLE(ios(15.0), tvos(15.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(watchOS);
@interface UIButtonConfiguration : NSObject <NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>
```

Whereas in Swift `configuration` is of type `UIButton.Configuration` which is a struct:

```
@MainActor public var configuration: UIButton.Configuration?
public struct Configuration : Hashable { ... }
```

Why `UIKit` headers generated for swift are not just "translated" to Swift one-to-one? Why must the type of `configuration` be different in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C does not support [Swift nested types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/nestedtypes/)

At a general level since the introduction of Swift, UIKit has been 'swiftyfied' in some areas for improved ease of use, the Swift team referred to this as 'the grand renaming'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to "the grand renaming" term. Although it seems that it's all about names conversion, whereas in the case of 'configuration' property they changed a value type

Comment: the button configuration APIs are from iOS15, so presumably they are 'converted' back from Swift into ObjC